# Mercurial find illegal name while PULL

Tags: mercurial

I pulled my project from bitbucket. Then at merging it mercurial says: `abort: filename contains ':', which is reserved on Windows: 'uploads/images/ \xd1\x8d\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 - 29.03.2012 - 19:41:35.png'`

How I can remove this file from repo? I don't need it, but it aborts merging. I don't see this file in folder in Windows.

Comment: I would imagine that you can't really do anything about it on Windows.

Comment: Clone from any **non-Windows system**, rewrite history, push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a windows system you could do something like this:

```
hg clone --noupdate PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO
hg debugsetparent tip
hg remove --after "uploads/images/\xd1\x8d\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 - 29.03.2012 - 19:41:35.png"
hg commit "uploads/images/\xd1\x8d\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 - 29.03.2012 - 19:41:35.png"
```

After that you could update and then merge.  Probably easier just to do it on an OS with a more forgiving file system though.